# Issue on copying file from internal storage to sdcard

Tags: android, file, root

I tried to read a file from this path: **data/data/com.example.app/shared_prefs/data.xml**. I made a small textview in my app to show some logs. it showed me the stacktrace: **/data/data/com.example.app/shared_prefs/data.xml (Permission denied)**  I gave the app superuser permissions and added these permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml --> android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE & android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. But it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving superuser permissions to an app does not change anything as those permissions are not automatically used: superuser permissions means that you have the permission to execute something with root permissions but you don't have root permissions!

For using superuser permissions you have to execute an external application using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(..) and you have to execute it using the "su" binary. All operations performed by the external application will then be executed using superuser permission.

BTW: If you have busybox installed you can use "cp" (file copy) as the external application.